# Can selection bias be solved by including control variables?

Tags: propensity-scores, heckman, selection-bias

Omitted variable bias can be solved by including covariates that are omitted. However, can selection bias also be solved by including covariates?

Comment: By selection bias, do you mean the bias resulting from conditioning on consequences of the treatment and outcome? This term is used differently in different disciplines.

Comment: You can control only for measured variables, by definition. In addition, such adjustment is generally inefficient or with incomplete coverage. That is why randomized trials remain superior to observational studies or non-randomized trials..

Comment: @Noah yes I mean that kind of selection bias